# Unity black bars Iphone X

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-container, iphone-x

Im using an emulator and it adds the black bars on top and bottom. I tried changing the game resolution:
[image]

I created a canvas with the correct size and image:
[image]

And even tried to change via code the Resolution:

```
    void Start () {
    Screen.SetResolution(1125, 2436, true);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? why there are black bars in the emulator (the one im using is Unity Remote)

Comment: Is the emulator set with the correct size?

Comment: I think so, the emulator is an app that launches the game when connected via USB and in unity I don't see a way to change the settings for that emulator. and In the app there is no menu or options but I don't think it matters as its the actual device size (correct me if im wrong)

Comment: If it works correctly on unity's game screen, it should work fine for devices of same resolution, these black bars may be a bug of the simulator.
The "Game Resolution" that you changed does not affect the program at all, it just tells the program the size of the screen in which it's gonna be executed (inside unity, in game screen), it has nothing to do with an external simulator as far as I know.