# Black bars iPhone X above. How to get rid of?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble with these strange black bars on the edges of iPhone X devices and higher. They will fade in and out weirdly with the camera and mess up my UI layout. Any suggestions for how to fix this? I am using the Unity game engine to create the game.
Video with demonstration linked below:
youtu.be/FFZe--izo_k

Comment: There is a safe area designated on a lot of phones with bevels, notches or cameras places over the screen. It could be a [bug in the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864094/unity-black-bars-iphone-x) you are using which is continually toggling on and off the use of this safe area. Better yet, [here is a solution](https://forum.unity.com/threads/canvashelper-resizes-a-recttransform-to-iphone-xs-safe-area.521107/) to properly scale your canvases to this safe area.

Comment: I know its not a simulator bug, because it was happening on my iPhone 11 device as well.

Comment: Check the second link in my comment. Is your entire game screen on a `Canvas` object? Or are they 2D sprites?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the animation is messing up the ui. Do you have any code that you think is related to that issue? If so, please edit your post with the code. Until then I can't help you. One other issue that might be that something is messing up the camera. Hope this helps in some way! :D

Comment: I dont know really how to code in Unity, I use an asset called Adventure Creator which includes visual scripting. I have attached below the scripts that control the cameras:
https://file.io/fvZf3aWZDeIv
https://file.io/0OL5NHJd0zp7
NOTE: These C# scripts were not created by me.

Comment: the link doesn't work, if you don't mind, please edit your post with the necessary scripts. Also, usually assets are meant for a specific version of unity, so if you have a later or newer version of unity, some assets won't work even if there's no errors in the console.